# How to make an object from a remote api serializable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice, android-intentservice

I am currently working on my first exercises in using services to handle networking operations. My first app idea involves fetching a stock quote with some history using the YahooFinanceApi https://financequotes-api.com/#singlestock-hist
The issue I have at the moment is returning the object (Stock) to the game activity to be displayed. I have understood that i need to use serializable or parcelable however since I am only to use this once I figured serializable required less coding. However the putExtra don't seem to recognice my Stock variable called stockInfo as something that I can transfer. Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

The StockPullService file is written as follows.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import yahoofinance.Stock;
import yahoofinance.YahooFinance;
import yahoofinance.histquotes.Interval;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class StockPullService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TICKER = "ticker";

    public StockPullService() {
        super("StockPullService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Service Started");
        if(workIntent != null) {
            int toMonth = (int) (-1 * Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)); //Randomises what month to end on a

            Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance(); //Makes a calendar from point
            Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance(); //Makes a calendar to point
             from.add(Calendar.MONTH, toMonth - 5); //From a random number of months ago
             to.add(Calendar.MONTH, toMonth); //To 5 months later (To accomodate     for 20 weeks of guesses)

            try {
                Stock stockInfo = YahooFinance.get(workIntent.getStringExtra(TICKER), from, to, Interval.WEEKLY);
                 Log.d(TAG, "Service Successful");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service Failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intentResponse = new Intent();
            intentResponse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intentResponse.putExtra("FetchedStock", stockInfo);
            Log.d(TAG, "Service Completed");
        }

    }
}
```

And the game activity is as follows.

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StockPullService.class);
    intent.putExtra(StockPullService.TICKER, "HM-B.ST");
    startService(intent);

    Stock stock = (Stock) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FetchedStock");
}
```

}

Comment: please, show us your Stock class

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I guess that this is the problem, the Stock class is just something that is obtained from the YahooFinanceAPI. So it is not a class that I have written myself. I guess that the Stock class does not implement Serializable and that is what is causing the issue, but how do I change that on a class I get from a ready API?

Comment: You can impleemnt the class yourself in your project and reference it instead of this remote class. Just copy the parementers from the orginal class and implement the serializable interface and the parse method.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque sorry if this is a dumb question but how do I do that in a good way, do I need to download the jar files for the API or is there any simpler way of importing the class as a new class into my project in android studio?

Comment: If you Ctrl+click in the Stock class you'll be able to see it internally, then just make a class with the same params

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque this clashes with the YahooFinance.get method since the Stock class I created is not compatible and it only looks for the YahooFinance.Stock class. is there any way of making my class compatible or do I need to reimplement the entire YahooFinance class aswell? Thank you for all your help, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Change the name of your class to LocalStock and use it instead of Stock

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque 
Yeah I changed the name to StockTemp and wrote the following
StockTemp stockInfo = YahooFinance.get(....) but it is labled as incomaptible types. So my local version of the Stock class seems to be incompatible with recieving the info
And I cant just cast the second part as (StockTemp) either

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serializable wrapper for `Stock` as follows:

```
public class SerializableStock implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Stock stock;

    public SerializableStock(final Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Stock getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
        stream.writeObject(stock.getSymbol());
        stream.writeObject(stock.getName());
        // TODO: serialize the rest of the fields
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.stock = new Stock((String) stream.readObject());
        this.stock.setName((String) stream.readObject();
        // TODO: deserialize and set the rest of the fields
    }
}
```

wrap it before serializing in `StockPullService`:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    ...
    intentResponse.putExtra("FetchedStock", new SerializableStock(stockInfo));
    ...
}
```

and unwrap it `GameActivity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Stock stock = ((SerializableStock) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FetchedStock")).getStock();
}
```

Comment: So with the serialization i just go object after object, preforming the same writeObject code you wrote above with name currency and so forth to finish the process. But the deserialization how is that handled for the other fields than the Stock itself that you made an example of above?

Comment: You will have to deserialize and set fields yourself. I have updated the code with an example handling the `name` field.

Comment: Will it be the same for the values that depend on other classes like     private List<HistoricalQuote> history; or can I just use this.stock.setName((List<HistoricalQuote>) stream.readObject();?

Comment: The same treatment will be needed for all classes that do not implement  `java.io.Serializable`. So, yes, you'd need a wrapper for `HistoricalQuote` as well. But, obviously, bear in mind, you might want to skip certain fields if you are not interested in those as you are in complete control with this approach.

Comment: When I use the same line you wrote to use in the Game Activity I get a null pointer exception, this is even if I only handle name, currency and so fort (the strings) do you have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: I have seen your separate question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097901/nullpointerexception-on-serialization-and-deserialization-wrapper-class. The `NullPointerException` problem is not related to serialization/deserialization